# Create new GeoJSON LineString from JSON objects using a property

Tags: python, json, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I would like to combine several Json objects into a GeoJSON feature collection with LineStrings

For example I have the following badly formatted json objects:

```
 {"lat":16.0269337,"lon":40.073042,"score":1,"ID":"13800006252028","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Strada Statale della Val Sinni"}
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006260148","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"}
{"lat":16.0316523,"lon":41.6808932,"score":1,"ID":"13800006260148","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2","NAME":"Giro del Gargano"}
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006203620","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"}
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006203620","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Giro del Gargano"}
{"lat":16.032322,"lon":40.6097567,"score":1,"ID":"13800005963252","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"}
{"lat":16.032322,"lon":40.6097567,"score":1,"ID":"13800005963252","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Via Appia"}
```

I am aiming to do two things

1. Use the IDs to create GeoJson linestrings if the ID & same type is the same
2. add the score of the matching json files up based on the score property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but here's a first cut.  [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220997/pandas-to-geojson-multiples-points-features-with-python) was helpful to get the basics. There are probably more elegant approaches than mine to the each of the "Geo", "JSON", and pandas manipulation pieces.

It's not immediately clear what exact format your data is in, but you are either going to be able to directly import it if its really a list of dictionaries using `pd.DataFrame` or directly from the JSON file using `pd.from_json`.  I'm just working with the former but its an easy change.

```
json_objs = [{"lat":16.0269337,"lon":40.073042,"score":1,"ID":"13800006252028","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Strada Statale della Val Sinni"},
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006260148","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"},
{"lat":16.0316523,"lon":41.6808932,"score":1,"ID":"13800006260148","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2","NAME":"Giro del Gargano"},
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006203620","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"},
{"lat":16.0316522,"lon":41.6808931,"score":1,"ID":"13800006203620","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Giro del Gargano"},
{"lat":16.032322,"lon":40.6097567,"score":1,"ID":"13800005963252","TYPES":"Scenic","N2C":"2"},
{"lat":16.032322,"lon":40.6097567,"score":1,"ID":"13800005963252","TYPES":"Regional","N2C":"2","NAME":"Via Appia"}
```

Then work with pandas to manipulate the data and create LineString objects using the geojson package

```
import geojson
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(json_objs)

grouped = df.groupby(["ID","TYPES"])
features = []

for name,indices in grouped.groups.items():
    group = df.iloc[indices]

    score = group["score"].sum()   
    points = list(zip(group["lat"].values,group["lon"].values))    
    properties = {"ID": name[0], "record_type": name[1], "score": score}

    ls = geojson.LineString(coordinates = points, properties = properties)
    print(ls)

    features.append(ls)
```

Output:

```
{"coordinates": [[16.032322, 40.6097567]], "properties": {"ID": "13800005963252", "record_type": "Scenic", "score": 1}, "type": "LineString"}
{"coordinates": [[16.0269337, 40.073042]], "properties": {"ID": "13800006252028", "record_type": "Regional", "score": 1}, "type": "LineString"}
{"coordinates": [[16.032322, 40.6097567]], "properties": {"ID": "13800005963252", "record_type": "Regional", "score": 1}, "type": "LineString"}
{"coordinates": [[16.0316522, 41.6808931], [16.0316523, 41.6808932]], "properties": {"ID": "13800006260148", "record_type": "Scenic", "score": 2}, "type": "LineString"}
{"coordinates": [[16.0316522, 41.6808931]], "properties": {"ID": "13800006203620", "record_type": "Scenic", "score": 1}, "type": "LineString"}
{"coordinates": [[16.0316522, 41.6808931]], "properties": {"ID": "13800006203620", "record_type": "Regional", "score": 1}, "type": "LineString"}
```

Then turn those `LineStrings` into a `FeatureCollection`:

```
feature = geojson.FeatureCollection(features)
```

Obviously you could manually construct this format as well, but I'd expect that `geojson` gives you additional flexibility.  There is apparently also a `geopandas` package that I couldn't get installed.

Comment: your iterator can just be: `for name, group in df.groupby(["ID","TYPES"])`: